# How to modify the link text(html link) properties using css

Tags: html, css

I have been trying to mimic a link styled as a button using css of this website-http://simpleblend.net/  (The learn more button) So far i did this but on hover when i try to re-size or re position the whole div gets affected along with link text.

P.S- Extreme newbie pls go on easy in the comments

My code

```
CSS
.learn
{
font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
background-color: transparent;
border:2px solid #fff;
color: white;
padding:.8em;
position: absolute;
left: 43.6%;
top:24em;
font-size: 18pt;
}

.learn:hover
{
background-color: white;
color: black; 
font-size: 5pt;
} 

HTML
<a class="learn">Learn More</a>
```

Comment: dont go position absolte. give the button a size.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nmmbdgts/
and now you can start altering it yourself. have fund

Comment: Well, you drastically change the `font-size` when you `:hover`, so that is why it resizes.

Comment: @putvande How to prevent it from resizing ?

Comment: By not changing the `font-size`? Or like @huanson suggested: give it a size so it is both the same normal and on hover.

Comment: @putvande Nope even after assigning a width and height, when i try to the link text font size it still re-sizes. How to change the font size without loss of resizing?

Comment: You define a `padding` in `em`. That means it is going to change the padding according to your font size. So when the font-size gets smaller, so does your padding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You set the offset from the `top` and the `padding` using `em`. `em` is an unit which refers to the current font size of the element. So if you change the font size the position and size of the element also changes. Use a percentage (`%`) or pixel (`px`) value instead or do not position the element as `absolute` at all.

The size of the element is also affected when you change the font size cause the element has no explicit width or height, so it fits it's content. To give an `a` tag a size you have to make it a `block` element using `display: block`.

I changed your example to let the button behave like the one on the website you mentioned. My example does not use any Javascript. The animations also could be done using some JS framework like jQuery.

```css
.learn {
  width: 200px;
  height: 60px;
  font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:2px solid #fff;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 18pt;
  line-height:60px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.learn a {
  color: white;
  display: block;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover {
  background-color: white;
}
.learn:hover a {
  color: black;
  margin-left: -20px;
}
.learn span {
  background:url(data:image/gif;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAkAAAAQCAYAAADESFVDAAAAGXRFWHRTb2Z0d2FyZQBBZG9iZSBJbWFnZVJlYWR5ccllPAAAAElJREFUeNqMj0EKADEIAx3//+f0siyF1iaCIDLEsapKX4/V26wEGsG+7JRAB9gPXyXQD+LeT5JiCAfhknDncE44cdx3THJLgAEAR9cJHGy5GicAAAAASUVORK5CYII=) center center;
  display: block;
  width: 9px;
  height: 16px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 22px;
  left: 110%;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.learn:hover span{
  left: 80%;
}
body {
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="learn">
  <a>Learn More</a>
  <span></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there a way to repostion it towards the left? When i use the left or right it kinda pushes the away the whole div

Comment: I do not exactly understand what you mean. Could you provide a more detailed description or an image of the expected result?

Comment: The learn more button in this link -http://simpleblend.net/  . I am kinda stuck on that.Thanks in advance

Comment: @RenzousRakesh check my improved solution above. Does this match your expectations?

Comment: Thank, just as i needed

Answer (score 0):

Set `height` and `width` to the element, `display: table-cell` for vertical alignment. Now you can change `font-size` on hover and the size of button will remain unaltered.

```css
body {
  background-color: #33b;
}
.learn {
    font-family: 'Open Sans',sans-serif;
    border:2px solid #fff;
    color: #fff;
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 200px;
    height: 40px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-size: 14px;
}
.learn:hover {
    background-color: white;
    color: black;
    font-size: 18px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#" class="learn">Learn more</a>
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I just figured this, i just want to know how to reposition the text as in moving it towards the left with moving the whole button

Comment: @RenzousRakesh do you still want to change font-size on hover?